# Background is not working in before pseudoclass

Tags: html, css

I would like to add icons before `nav` item text. In my `nav` I have list of elements and when I try to add `pseudoclass` to `li` element it is working, but background image that's not showing. I tried to use this same path in another element and that's working in body and other elements. My `nav` looks like: 
And my style is:

```css
li.nav-item.my-account:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: url("../images/icons/user.svg") no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<ul>
            <li class="nav-item my-account"><a href="{{ route('summary') }}">My Account</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: I think path of image is not correct. Can you tried with absolute path of image?

Comment: I copied absolute path using Phpstorm and that's still not working.

Comment: Maybe it's an issue with the svg file? Have you tried png or jpeg (just for testing purposes)

Comment: Png file is also not working. I tried to use that svg file in body and other html elements and there is showing so path and file are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```css
 li.nav-item.my-account:before {
        content: '';
        display: inline-block;
        width: 15px;
        height: 15px;
        background: url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/33/33281.png) no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
        margin: 10px;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    
li {
list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
            <li class="nav-item my-account"><a href="{{ route('summary') }}">My Account</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: Still nothing :(

Comment: Run my code snippet it is working. Please double check your image path.

Comment: you have to give background-position and background-size as well.

Comment: I did that and that wasn't working in my project. My image path is correct because when I will add that background to body or another element that will be working and my svg file is showing.